# How do they achieve animate tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I was wondering if anyone knew how PanelFly (panelfly.com) got the animated tabs. Is it a custom script or is it a plugin?

Thanks in advance,

Marc180

Comment: What does this have to with Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All they look like they are doing is on click they simply use fadeOut(250) and then fadeIn(250) of a div.

There are plugins for this sure, but for the fading it's just fadeIn and fadeOut.

Moving the pointer can be achieved using jQuery animate in which you can animate an item across the screen.  Animate is documented here http://api.jquery.com/animate/  In fact, the second demo in the examples section does this exactly.

After that it's just a bunch of pretty pictures and css placement of div's etc.

Answer (score 0):

Their JS is minified and concatenated so this isn't as readable as it could be, but it looks like they wrote a fairly simple jQuery plugin to detect if CSS3 transitions are available and animate the slider and pointer and change tabs. Pretty straightforward stuff:

```
$(function () {
var n = {};
n.transition = function () {
    var k = (document.body || document.documentElement).style;
    return k.transition !== void 0 || k.WebkitTransition !== void 0 || k.MozTransition !== void 0 || k.MsTransition !== void 0 || k.OTransition !== void 0
}();
$("section.tabs").each(function () {
    var k = $(this),
        O = k.find("nav li");
    O.click(function (T) {
        var u = $(this);
        if (!u.hasClass("active")) {
            O.removeClass("active");
            n.transition ? u.addClass("active") : u.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 300, function () {
                u.addClass("active")
            });
            var A = u.prevAll(),
                G = k.find("ul.content li");
            G.removeClass("active");
            setTimeout(function () {
                var k = $(G[A.length]);
                n.transition ? k.addClass("active") : k.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 300, function () {
                    k.addClass("active")
                })
            }, 100);
            var Y = u.position();
            $(k.find(".pointer:first")).animate({
                left: Y.left
            }, 700, function () {})
        }
        T.preventDefault()
    })
})
```

});